# Capturing the last group: everything when the first character appears

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture everything after and including the first non-digit character in the following text:

```
1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                  00814766
                                                            P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                            COLTON CA  92324
```

For example, I would want regex to capture groups in a way that it matches: `1`, `1,486,399.87`, `5`, and `ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED 00814766 P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288 COLTON CA  92324`.

The code I have right now is:

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import docx2txt
import textract
import antiword
import itertools

# text
t = "    1         1,486,399.87    5              ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED
                                                                                                  00814766
                                                            P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288
                                                            COLTON CA  92324"

tt = re.search(r"(\d+)\s+(\$?[+-]?\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*%?(\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S*)", t)

ttgroup = len(tt.groups())

print(tt[ttgroup])
```

It returns only `ORTIZ`. I suppose we need to improve the (S*) grouping towards the end of the pattern. Is there a way we could capture the entire `ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED 00814766 P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288 COLTON CA  92324` in the last group? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sidenote: Are all those imports really needed for this? Also, my python (3.11.1) says `unterminated string literal (detected at line` and the line number where `t` is defined.

Comment: Sidenote2: After fixing the syntax error mentioned above, your `tt.groups()` contains `('1', '1,486,399.87', ',399', '.87', '5', 'ORTIZ')` but you only print `ORTIZ`.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo - I am trying to split the text in a way that the last group contains `ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED 00814766 P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288 COLTON CA  92324` - but right now, the last group is `ORTIZ`. Thanks!

Comment: Thinking about a way to capture `ORTIZ ASPHALT PAVING INC              909 386-1200  SB PREF CLAIMED 00814766 P O BOX 883                       FAX 909 386-1288 COLTON CA  92324`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace the last group, that is now `(\S*)`, with `(\S.*)` since you want to capture the rest of the string. Also add the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag since this is a multiline string:

```py
tt = re.search(r"(\d+)\s+(\$?[+-]?\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*%?(\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S.*)", t, re.DOTALL)
```